# Exclusively restricting .py to read certain lines when sending query from html frontend

Tags: python, flask

I have a .py file in which I read data from various sources and applied some logics and came up with a final output data.

Now I created a html form which ask for an input and when user gives input it searches for the output file in .py file and return the row entries corresponding to that input value.

Now the problem is everytime when user gives an input , it executes all my .py file at backend which causes lot of time to display result on html page which is connected with my .py.

Suppose I have below code:

```
#Importing Libraries
 import pyodbc
 import pandas as pd
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests
 from itertools import zip_longest
 import re
 import numpy as np
 import csv
 from IPython.display import display, HTML
 import xlrd
 import smtplib, os, cgi
 from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
 from email.mime.text import MIMEText
#imported necessary drivers and established connection with database
 [x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith('Microsoft Access Driver')]
conn_str = (
   r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\\Users\\test.accdb;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

for table_info in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
    print(table_info.table_name)

#Read abc data from datbase
sql= "SELECT * from abc"
RMA = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
```

After the above codes I applied some functions and came up with the final output dataframe.

I ahve successfully connected it to HTML frond end also but the problem is its reading the entire .py file each time user enters an input.

Is this anything which I can add in the code so that it will directly read output file for say(1 hour ) when .py file will be called again immediately within 1 hour or anytime frame instead of executing entire thing.

Means when .py will be called again it will read from some specific line and fetch the result saved already in outfile at the first execution.

Please suggest.

Comment: Define a function, and call that function. The function should encapsulate the logic that should be used everytime. You can define constants to use. Furthermore, you better use an ORM than raw queries.

Comment: Where exacly you are using django?

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer** Create one function to do whatever you want and call it by ajax time by time when you need to upload your data at your template... or setup one view in django and bind to one url, everytime you call this url he will call this view (function) and process what you want

**Suggestions:** First you should using MVC to split your logic between your projects... django uses MVT(Models Views Template) that is somethings like regular MVC...

Using Django models he can handle with your database connection, so you dont need to open and close it everytime, just need to call.

Using Django Views you can easily router your project and place your html being called by one view with the context (data that you want to fetch), earch url will call one view.

Like i said in quick answer, if you dont want to upload your entire page you can use Javascript to make one asyncronous call (using ajax) to your backend and execution one function that will return the fetched data that you want.

**Some helpful links**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp